# php code or script to accept value in textbox from autocomplete list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

In my form there is an autocomplete textbox.

I am selecting multiple values from this textbox like below ..

> 701,702,703,

every thing is working fine.

BUT the problem is textbox also accept those values which is not in database or not comes in autocomplete list.

For example my table has 3 values:

```
700
701
702
```

this value comes in autocomplete textbox...

but if user enter 700,701,702,1000000,

**this value 1000000 is not in database **

Thats why  i need to ask  you is there is any script or code or javascript which make my  textbox only accept those values which comes in autocomplete list  only.

below is my code and script...

```
<input id="tags" type="text" class="field size2"  name="used_receipt">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
<?php 
$receipt = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT SM.receipt_no FROM scheme_master SM Inner join book_issue BI ON BI.book_no = SM.Book_no2  where SM.receipt_no not in (select used_receipt from book_return)"); 
foreach($receipt as $row){ ?>
"<?php echo $row['receipt_no']; ?>",
<?php } ?>
];
function split( val ) {
return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tags" )
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
$( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
event.preventDefault();
}
})
.autocomplete({
minLength: 0,
source: function( request, response ) {
// delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
},
focus: function() {
// prevent value inserted on focus
return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
var terms = split( this.value );
// remove the current input
terms.pop();
// add the selected item
terms.push( ui.item.value );
// add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
terms.push( "" );
this.value = terms.join( ", " );
return false;
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you create fiddle of your code

Comment: yes i created fiddle of my code ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to write your own code to do this.

What you could do is add the event "blur" to your input, and when it triggers (which means it loses focus), you check the value to see if it is allowed or not.

```
$("#tags").on("blur", function(){
    if (availableTags.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1)
    {
        //Not allowed:
        $(this).val("");
        //You could also put a warning here or something.   
    }
});
```

Comment: @varshabajpai Just to be sure: you did change the "yourArrayWithAllowedValues" to the right name, right?

Comment: I replaced it, in your code you use "availableTags" as array.

Comment: Can you tell me what is in "availableTags" when you fill it up?

Comment: I found an error in my code and corrected it. Can you try now?

Comment: i tried yor new code ..this is working...but wont work as i want....for ex - in my listbox there are  suppose 2 values ok....values are 700 and 701 ok  now i select 700 from autocomplete list. again i select 701 from list and tab change then it also clear all values of lisatbox everytime......

Comment: i need textbox clear those values which is not available in autocomplete listbox